Prayers for the Intentions of the Pope
Consider the published monthly prayer intentions by Pope Francis for 2024:
The Monthly Prayer Intentions of Pope Francis for 2024
When Catholics say, for example, a family Rosary or perform some other indulgenced work, prayers for the intentions of the Holy Father are prescribed.
QUESTION: When Catholics say prayers for the intentions of the Pope, what exactly are they praying for? Is it for the specific intention promulgated by the Pope for that particular month? If not, consider what Fr. F. W. Faber says on p. 285 of The Precious Blood:

If we pray for the intentions of the Sovereign Pontiff, it is the sweet Spirit-guided will of the Church, which we are assisting to its accomplishment.

